# Get User Story Collection for Iterations using APP SDK 2.1

Tags: javascript, rally

I'm trying to get all the User Stories allocated to a given Iteration to compute some metrics. I can successfully get all the iterations, but can't figure out a builtin way to get its user stories. From the documentation (and various other places), I've read about Hierarchical Requirement which doesn't seem to be apart of the App SDK and am now pursuing Collections.

```
this.iterationRecords = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'Iteration',
        fetch: ["Name", START_DATE_FIELD, END_DATE_FIELD, "ObjectID", "State", "PlannedVelocity", "UserStories"], //Having trouble grabbing User Stories
            sorters: [
                {property: START_DATE_FIELD, direction: "DESC"},
                {property: END_DATE_FIELD, direction: "DESC"},
                {property: "State", operator: "=", value: "Accepted"}
            ],
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            load: function(store, records) {
                console.log(records);
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HierarchicalRequirement is just a fancy name for user story.  You are correct that there is no direct collection on an iteration which contains its scheduled items.  However it is fairly straightforward to query for them.

```
this.storiesInIteration = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
    model: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
    fetch: ["FormattedID", "Name"],
    filters: [{
        property: 'Iteration.Name',
        value: 'My Iteration'
    }]
    autoLoad: true,
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records) {
            console.log(records);
        }
    }
});
```

Note that Rally has the concept of "like iterations"- there are often many iterations with the same name, start and end dates (one for each project in a hierarchy).  That's what that little cascading iterations checkbox does when you create a new iteration, and that's why you have to filter for them by name rather than by ref.